# TinyTDS connection issues and return from SQL server 2008

Tags: ruby, tiny-tds

I have an issue with getting a result set back from SQL server 2008 using TinyTDS. My SQL server resides on my local machine and I am on a windows 7 machine.

my connection settings in the database.yml file is like this..

```
 development:
   adapter: sqlserver
   host: localhost
   database: database_name
   username: username
   password: password
   timeout: 5000

 client = TinyTds::Client.new(use the above settings)
 puts client.active?
 result = client.execute("select * from tablename")
 puts "#{result}"
```

the result I get when I print is

```
  true
  -1
```

Also I am not able to see all the methods that is available for the TinyTds::Client. I am guessing I am missing some setup. or have to add it somewhere.

Can anyone help me or suggest what I am doing wrong here..

Comment: Seems like you are doing everything correct. Are you sure targeted table exist in the database? Returned result is Enumerable, `result.first` should be a hash with fields as keys. For Client methods run `client.methods`, but as far as I know `execute` is the main used to run SQL statements.

Comment: @Simon, thanks for the response mate, the table does exist in the database. but I am not sure what else I need to do..

Comment: and sometimes this is what I get 

"#<TinyTds::Result:0x5833908>"

Comment: "#<TinyTds::Result:0x5833908>" seems like you get your result. Can you  print it out using `awesome_print` library, like this: `ap result.first` instead of `puts "#{result}"`. Also, `-1` seems like error code. Can you try to print out `result.first.[:Error]`(capital E) and `result.first[:Message]`(capital M)? Cheers

Comment: I have done all this mate, tiny_tds seems to be not working and throws exception with first[:Error] and first[:Message]...I have given up, unfortunately I don't have the time to debug some core issues with this whole tiny_tds product or my setup and go with the obvious ActiveRecord and ruby-odbc. But since then installing and removing tiny_tds now I can't even configure Activerecord with ruby-odbc see my other request plight

Comment: I appreciate your help with this and apols for the late response, was quite caught up with some other work

Answer (score 0):

Check out the README for TinyTDS, if you are going to use the low level connection mode vs the adapter, you need to use the client/result object properly. In this case, do `data = client.execute("select * from tablename").each`. Notice that I am calling the each method on the result object to get the data back.

Answer (score 0):

For a successfully working TinyTDS you should call

```
TinyTds::Client.new(all other params, :tds_version => 100)
```

It is important to give the tds_version parameter.